# Is it possible to use PHPExcel to edit an existing template file, and maintain existing formatting / spreadsheet objects

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm looking for a server-side (PHP) way of manipulating / producing xls / xlsx files from MySQL data.

I have an existing template xls file, with various relatively complicated cell dependant formulas and charts and such included, my hope is that I can upload this template file to my server and use PHPExcel to edit that file, and save it: allowing it to be downloaded.

So my formulas are kept, the charts are kept, and I simply have to edit the data for certain cells based on values from the database --> charts drawn based on these values.

Is that kind of thing within PHPExcels remit?

Reading a related question here:
[PHPExcel modify existing .xlsx file with multiple worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594444/phpexcel-modify-existing-xlsx-file-with-multiple-worksheet)

Someone stated:

> Macros and User-Defined Functions are not supported in PHPExcel; and
>   the library discards any unsupported features of a workbook when it is
>   loaded, so they don't exist in the PHPExcel object at all... when
>   saving, PHPExcel only saves those elements of the workbook that exist
>   in the PHPExcel object.

Would a user defined function include simple cell formulas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. Simple cell formulas will still be there. Just not any VBA code.

Answer (score 2):

PHPExcel can handle quite complex cell formulae, though it does have some limitations:

- Only 316 out of 356 functions for Excel 2007 are currently supported, and those that are don't necessarily implement all features of the function
- None of the additional functions for Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 are supported
- Analysis toolpack functions aren't support for Excel BIFF files
- VBA script is not supported, this includes any user-defined functions
- Array formulae aren't supported
- 3D-cell references are not supported