# editing an Excel 2007 document with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have en excel 2007 document with 10 sheets but when I try to edit it with PHPExcel all the contents of those sheets (except the first one and the input made with PHPExcel) are erased.

Here is my code:

```
require 'PHPExcel.php';
require 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$fileName = 'test.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

$activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexbyName('ID');
$activeSheet->setCellValue('A2', 'string test');

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save($fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594444/phpexcel-modify-existing-xlsx-file-with-multiple-worksheet) try rearranging your code like this:

```
require 'PHPExcel.php';
require 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$fileName = 'test.xlsx';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->load($fileName);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexbyName('ID');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', 'string test');

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save($fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I get the error message : Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::setLoadAllSheets()

Comment: Thanks but now i have the error message : Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getSheetByName()

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to test but here is one other idea:  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexbyName($sheet['ID']);